# converting columns in pandas dataframe into datetime

Tags: python, pandas

```
  gps   nt_date 
   4002  20-Dec-16 
   4002  20-Dec-16 
    C-4  30-Jan-17 
 Y21-21  17-Nov-16 
    49a  22-Dec-16
```

In the dataframe above, how can I convert `nt_date` column to pandas datetime? I am using this but it does not work:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['nt_date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You're using slightly wrong directives. Try using `%b` (Month as locale’s abbreviated name) and `%y` (2 digit year, rather than `%Y` which is 4 digit):

```
df['nt_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['nt_date'], format='%d-%b-%y')

>>> df
      gps    nt_date
0    4002 2016-12-20
1    4002 2016-12-20
2     C-4 2017-01-30
3  Y21-21 2016-11-17
4     49a 2016-12-22
```

For more info, you can refer to [these docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)